# Should I worry about outages upon auto-rollover of ADFS token certificates?

Tags: ssl-certificate, adfs

As far as I understand ADFS self-manages the token signing and decryption certificates unless configured otherwise so in my current situation (see attached picture) there should be no need to do anything, am I correct ?

Also, should I expect the old certificate (which is now Secondary) to be deleted upon expiration ?

(Everything is working fine now, I'd just like to be reasonably sure nothing is going to blow up unexpectedly)

[image: ADFS Certificates screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ADFS PoV, no need to do anything.

Yes - certificate removed.

However, any CP and RP that do not automatically pick up the new metadata will break as they will think that the token is incorrectly signed.

These need to be updated manually.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to disagree with the accepted answer. In my experience, a typical relying party:

- Doesn't automatically pick up the new metadata
- Definitely has an outage every time there's a certificate rollover
- Is completely surprised when I report the outage, even if it's happened 3 consecutive years
- Doesn't know how to use the metadata and requires me to email them the certificate instead

So yes, worry.

My largest relying party, Google, doesn't seem to implement the automatic metadata update, and only provides a single upload slot for the certificate, which means there's no way to do the smooth transition. You have to upload the certificate to Google the exact instant it becomes Primary on the ADFS server, or you have an outage.

(I assume the purpose of having both certificates in the metadata is to allow relying parties to actually accept both of them during the overlap in their date ranges, which would make a smooth rollover possible. No such thing with Google.)

Even a more competent relying party, using ADFS on their end, failed to do the automatic update, and only succeeded in refreshing from the xml metadata by recreating the trust relationship from scratch.

Worry a lot.

Comment: I can confirm that, to this day, we need to go to each environment and act upon rollovers to avoid outages... Sad.